# How to remove the tzinfo completely from the time after converting to UTC in Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datetime, pytz, python-dateutil

I came across this exact [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12763938/why-doesnt-appengine-auto-convert-datetime-to-utc-when-calling-put), and I can't figure out how to achieve the solution in my case.

Guido says

> The solution is to remove the tzinfo completely from the time after
>   converting to UTC.

This is what I have tried:

```
        date_time = parser.parse(i.pubDate.text)
        news.publication_date = date_time.replace(tzinfo=None).date()
```

And I get the same error:

```
NotImplementedError: DatetimeProperty publication_date_time can only support UTC. Please derive a new Property to support alternative timezones.
```

So it seems I have to convert the date to UTC first. And here my research has failed me.

I came across this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357711/pytz-utc-conversion):

The solution suggested is this:

```
def date_time_to_utc(date_time):
        tz = pytz.timezone('???')
        return tz.normalize(tz.localize(date_time)).astimezone(pytz.utc)
```

But I don't have the timezone.  I am scraping the date from a html source.  So the timezone could really be from anywhere in the world.  Is there no easy and reliable way to convert a date time to UTC?
I could use both `dateutil` and `pytz` to achieve this. Many Thanks.

**UPDATE**
It has been a really long day. I have misread the stack trace. However the question remains valid.

```
date_time = (datetime}2015-01-13 18:13:26+00:00
news.publication_date_time = date_time
```

This caused the crash. And it seems by doing this, I pass the unit test:

```
news.publication_date_time = date_time.replace(tzinfo=None)
```

Is this the correct way converting a GMT 0 datetime to UTC datetime?  Or in fact any timezone to UTC?

Comment: The code you've posted ("This is what I have tried:") shows you turning your 'naive' datetime into a date, but the error is coming from a DatetimeProperty. Does the trace definitely lead to the code you've shown? It looks correct...

Comment: @Houman: you don't need `.replace(tzinfo=None)` before `.date()`. It returns a `date` object that is always naive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this the correct way converting a GMT 0 datetime to UTC datetime? Or in fact any timezone to UTC?

If `aware` datetime object is already in UTC (`+0000`) then your formula works:

```
naive_utc = aware_utc.replace(tzinfo=None)
```

where `aware_utc` is a timezone-aware datetime object that represents time in UTC.

But if `aware` datetime object is not in UTC; it fails. You should take into account a (possibly) non-zero UTC offset in the general case:

```
assert aware.tzinfo is not None and aware.utcoffset() is not None
# local time = utc time + utc offset (by definition)
# -> utc = local - offset
naive_utc = aware.replace(tzinfo=None) - aware.utcoffset()
```

where `aware` is a timezone-aware datetime object in an arbitrary timezone.

---

> But I don't have the timezone. I am scraping the date from a html
>   source. So the timezone could really be from anywhere in the world. Is
>   there no easy and reliable way to convert a date time to UTC? I could
>   use both dateutil and pytz to achieve this. Many Thanks.

No. `dateutil`, `pytz` won't help you unless the date string itself contains the timezone (or at least its utc offset).

Remember: It is *always* noon *somewhere* on Earth i.e., if you collect date/time strings from different places on Earth then you can't compare them unless you attach the corresponding timezones. You can't convert it to UTC, you can't get a valid POSIX timestamp if you don't know the source timezone for the date.

Comment: May you please explain what `aware_utc` means? Is GMT +1 an `aware_utc` ?

Comment: @Houman: yes. no.  `aware_utc` *always* has **zero** utc offset. GMT+1 implies 1 hour utc offset i.e., `GMT+1` is not `aware_utc`. Just use the formula that I've provided. It always works.

Comment: ah many thanks for the explanation. So if my datetime always shows in GMT it is safer to convert it like this: `naive_utc = aware.replace(tzinfo=None) - aware.utcoffset()`. Beware I live in UK, during winter time, our UTC/GMT offset is zero, hence looks the same. hence the date I provided above `date_time = (datetime}2015-01-13 18:13:26+00:00` should be GMT +0, It is not UTC. (Unless I am mixing it up and the format shown is actually UTC and GMT is written differently) :)

Comment: @Houman: yes. if the offset ever may be non-zero then you should use the more general formula.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot and it's late here, this time I read the question.

```
tstmp= date_time.replace(tzinfo=utc).total_seconds()
naive_date = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(tstmp)
```

First answer will just give you the current naive time

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dateTime = dateTime.replace(tzinfo=None)
dtUtcAware = pytz.UTC.localize(dateTime)
```